# Laravel Check Gmail Exist but contain characters as ".","+"

Tags: database, laravel, validation

I used rule exists for check Email has in database or not
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists

But I realize in Gmail can add characters as ".","+" without affecting the original Email
It means, a User can create so many account without use other Email
My question is

How do I can validate email exist in database which can prevent the above case?

Comment: Is this really useful? What about other mail servers that aren't Gmail? For instance I have configured a catchall address for my domain, I can use whatever email address I want (`<anything>@example.com`) and it'll go to my inbox... Or, even with Gmail, one could create a group and add itself as sole member, or configure a forwarding rule... Plus, you don't know if the user is using Gmail, because it can be G Suite (B2B) with Gmail. And on the other hand, if it's _not_ Gmail, the dot may actually make a difference. So... it sounds like it doesn't make a lot of sense what you are trying here.

Comment: You should always consider different email addresses - well - different. It's up to the user whether they are using some sort of setup where they can have multiple addresses go to the same inbox or not.

Comment: But If you has a system, you won't a User  can create so many account like as "e.xample@gmail.com, ex.ample@gmail.com....".  That makes it possible for users to create multiple accounts for the purpose of cross-interaction

Comment: Yeah I just meant that this doesn't really help, because there are many other ways to do the same. As I said, I can create whatever email address under my domain that I want, and you wouldn't know it's the same because I'm not using any `+` or `.`, just totally different username, but my server just sends it all to my same inbox. Or I could create tons of accounts using trashmail addresses, etc.

Comment: Thank @CherryDT, But I will continue wait someone will show a new solution

Answer (score 1):

so you don't want the user to register himself by entering email that contains dot and plus symbol. Simply use regular expressions to validate
whenever the enter email for registration, try to ensure that it is proper gmail address (or you can add validation for other mail addresses including domain names), if the email fullfils the condition, let the email inserted into the database
so simple

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).